# visual studio mvc 4 internet template has links to porn sites in dynamic script

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-9

I created a project in Visual Studio 2012 and chose: asp.net mvc 4, internet application, razor.

From first running on IE 9, no changes made, by clicking on any item menu IE throws this error: permission denied.

Using the IE scripts debugger I got the line that causes the error: if(b.utils.match_url(location.href,b.projects_info[a].urls))

I searched for this line in the code using visual studio and find out that this line is part of a dynamic script called 'script block'.

Doing a little analysis of this code I discovered a lot of tags of sexual meaning and links to porn sites and other odd sites. I don't know how they get there and don't know how to get rid of them either.

I'm trying to use this template for a small project but every time I create a project I get this spam that contains this line that throws the error of permission denied on IE but not on Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Where did you download the mvc4 install from? Also, maybe your dev box is compromised and it's managed to even manipulate the development server, not just the root IIS.

Comment: I downloaded the trial edition from the microsoft site. I changed the security settings of IE to the higher profile and the error is gone, also tried with no internet connection, and no error is prompted. I'm not sure where the spam attack comes from. I don't know if my code is already infected and every time it detects an internet connection or a safety vulnerability of the browser it attacks, or if my code is clean and I have to revise the hole security settings of my pc.

Comment: This is a new one,  sounds like a very infected computer.

Comment: I performed an anti-malware scan with Malwarebytes, it found this: C:\ProgramData\ccoonntinuetossave\519c72de46603.dll(PUP.Optional.MultiPlug.A). C:\Users\vito\AppData\Local\Temp\{2A35323D-8AEB-491C-BF7-C2C9F1D610CB}\Custom.dll(Trojan.MSIL.Injector).C:\Users\vito\AppData\Local\Temp\{2A35323D-8AEB-491C-ABF7-C2C9F1D610CB}\Addons\coupon_setup.exe (PUP.Adware.MultiPlug). I chose to delete this infected files, set IE security settings back to medium-high, did some testing with internet connection and the error is no longer prompted, the dynamic script 'script block' disappeared. I solved the prob!

Comment: I didn't know about any malware attacking 'work in progress' code before, interesting how they managed to infiltrate malicious code into our code very silently. if it wasn't for this error prompted by IE I would have continue working normaly with no suspect up to publishing maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an anti-malware scan (with Malwarebytes or some other) primarily seeking for Trojan.MSIL.Injector or similars.